# I have an augmented chord in a chord progression. How do I name it correctly? How do I know which inversion it is?

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, chord-inversions

I know the basics of constructing an augmented chord. What I don't understand is how to choose between the three inversions of an augmented chord in a specific context. For example, Bb augmented and Gb augmented use the same set of notes. Are they fully interchangeable chords? Or are there contexts that make one chord name more accurate than another?

(If it helps, I've taken that example from this sheet music of [Make you feel my love](http://hemli.dk/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Adele-Make-You-Feel-My-Love-SheetMusicCC.pdf) by Adele. The key is Bb. In the bridge there is a Gbaug chord. Could it equally have been Bbaug? Or for that matter, Daug?)

Comment: "Are they fully interchangeable chords? Or are there contexts that make one chord name more accurate than another?" In a way, "yes and yes." There are reasons to choose a particular spelling (see the duplicate). But the fun of symmetrical chords is that you can use them as a pivot, coming from one context and going into another by substituting a different "root."

Comment: There are likely several possible situations where the answer would be different for classical and jazz musicians.  That is certainly true of augmented sixth chords (tritone substitution in jazz, spelled as a diminished seventh chord).  Jazz tends to emphasize the spelling that most closely fits the key signature, whereas classical tends to emphasize voice leading and tonality.  So a B+ used as a substitute dominant in E major would have to be spelled like that in classical theory -- B, D sharp, F double sharp -- but a lead sheet would probably have G+/B or even E♭+/B.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the chord is very clearly rooted on G♭, just as the following chord is rooted on G♮.  They are named accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The bass motion is the giveaway. You have chromatic ascending bass motion for 3 chords in a row, Bb/F, Gb+, Eb/G. This creates a nice progression with the following voice leading that has some static and some moving notes: F-Gb-G, Bb-Bb-Bb, D-D-Eb.

A symmetrical chord like an augmented triad or a diminished 7th chord usually has no logical reason to be spelled as an inversion. After all Bb+/Gb is simply Gb+. Just guide yourself by what the bass note is or what it should be if you are composing or arranging.